# Calling Rest API in java from Hackerrank IDE

Tags: java, json, rest

I was trying to call an api like below. It works in my IDE(Intellij), where as it fails in hackerrank IDE while getting input stream.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
    
URL url = new URL("https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/article_users?page=1");  
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");  
connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
```

Getting an error:

```
error while calling: java.net.UnknownHostException: jsonmock.hackerrank.com
```

inside hacker rank IDE.

Please let me know your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

just remove s from https

URL url = new URL("http://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/article_users?page=1");

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure Hackerrank IDE has api call feature?

Perhaps for security or some other reason, this feature may be blocked or not supported.

Answer (score -1):

It may be the case that Hackerrank does not let Java code make outbound network requests. Similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631998/how-to-make-ajax-request-in-hackerrank-using-javascript) and [here](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/making-an-http-get-request-without-any-outside-dependencies/350760) suggest that you may need to choose a different language that Hackerrank supports. I imagine they should list it somewhere on their site, or on the IDE page directly.

Comment: It would be nice if they just didn't include Java in the list of languages... I couldn't even import the URL class in the test they created.